# How do I make a python script like answer = raw_input() if answer: BLAH import script

Tags: python, variables

How do I make a python script as:

```
answer = raw_input() if answer: "BLAH" then import script
```

Well I'm new to python and really programming altogether. I got this book on python called learning python by: Mark Lutz. no where in the book have i found out how to do this but I haven't read threw the book fully I have looked everywhere and found a little help but I'm hitting so many snares in development on this simple program. Could anyone help me on this one?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Computer-Science/dp/1887902996/

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> if raw_input("input something!:") == 'BLAH':
...     import some_module.py
... 
input something!:BLAH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named some_module.py
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
text = raw_input("import y/n: ")

if text == "y":
    import random #or whatever module you want

print random.uniform(10, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how you can set this up:

```
$ ls
__init__.py  main_script.py  simple_script.py

$ cat main_script.py 
if raw_input() == "BLAH":
    import simple_script

$ cat simple_script.py 
print "simple_script imported"

$ echo BLAH | python main_script.py 
simple_script imported
```